# I dont want my Bibliography to begin from a new page

Tags: bibliographies

I am pretty new on Latex. I am using the below packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}    
\usepackage[font=small,skip=1pt]{caption}    

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Computational Thinking}
\cfoot{Chapter \thechapter}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
```

When I am trying to add a `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` it starts from a new line. The previous page just has one line in the beginning and I want my bibliography to continue after it. I am unable to find it elsewhere. Please let me know what to do or please guide me as I might not be looking at the correct resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bibliography is supposed to be a chapter and so it starts in new page for report documentclass.

If Bibliography is your last printed "chapter" you can just use the command `\let\chapter=\section` before  bibliography:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}    
\usepackage[font=small,skip=1pt]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Computational Thinking}
\cfoot{Chapter \thechapter}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
 \chapter{test 1}
 \lipsum[1-5]
 \chapter{test 2}
 \lipsum[1-7]

\let\chapter=\section
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
\textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

\bibitem{einstein} 
Albert Einstein. 
\textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
[\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.

\bibitem{knuthwebsite} 
Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,
\\\texttt{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

If it is not the last chapter replace that command by:

```
\let\oldchapter=\chapter
\let\chapter=\section
```

and

```
\let\chapter=\oldchapter
```

just after printing bibliography.

**Note:** in both cases it will be a section of the last chapter but this might not be a problem for your documentclass and settings.

Comment: Since it is not the last chapter it worked with the replacement commands/

Comment: Just check your `tableofcontents` etc in case you have some other parameters there because if bibliography is printed in your tableofcontents it will be ugly as a section of last chapter. If it doesn't be printed as in my example it is ok.